# Неясности в описании блокировки пользователя

Tags: дефект, локализация, блокировка

Вот заблокированный пользователь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10815/typemoon у него в профиле вот такое вот сообщение отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что значит "заканчивается 2 май '17 в 19:00"? Второго мая 2017-го года в 19:00? Надо бы надпись эту сделать яснее, по всем правилам Великого и Могучего.

Comment: да, второго мая 2017 года в 19:00 )

Comment: «Чтобы позволить успокоиться», блокируют на сутки, максимум — на неделю. Годичный бан применяется с иной целью. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Если что, эта формулировка используется при блокировке за оскорбления и тому подобное плохое поведение. Даже если на год (когда не менее чем третье серьезное нарушение). Не то чтобы мы были уверены, что участник сейчас нервничал, а за год успокоится. Скорее просто не хотим подчищать за ним оскорбления в ближайший год.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Хочу переписать сообщение. Как добавить в него  ссылку и дату? Какие форматы поддерживает система и как ими управляют?

Comment: Что скажите про вариант «Дата окончания блокировки: 2 май '17 в 19:00»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "2 мая 2017 в 19:00" предпочтительнее, как мне кажется.

Comment: На сколько я вижу, одни и те же строки используются в нескольких местах (например, [в учетной записи участника](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11970/pyatak?tab=profile)). Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что используется _трех буквенные сокращения_, а не полные формы.